# How do I use prepared statements to store_result and then get_result?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

My code works without prepared statements, but once I try to use prepared statements everything breaks. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Prepared statements breaking everything:

```
$city = $_GET['city'];
$state = $_GET['state'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}



$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT lati, longi FROM geocode WHERE city=? AND state=? LIMIT 1");
$sql2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT state, city, lati, longi FROM geocode WHERE state=?");
$sql->bind_param('ss', $city, $state);
$sql2->bind_param('s', $state);
$sql->execute();
$sql2->execute();
$sql->store_result();
$sql2->store_result();
$sql->get_result();
$sql2->get_result();
```

Code that doesn't work with it:

```
if ($sql->num_rows >0) {

  //this doesn't work
  while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
     //this doesn't work
  }
```

I'm really confused here. I've tried `bind_result`, `get_result`, with and without `store_result`, `$sql->query()` etc. It does nothing.

Also this works as an API, but when I try to print the results, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried to run the exact SQL produced directly in Mysql to see if it gave you an error or results?

Comment: Yes, it works. Just tried again to make sure. Everything worked perfectly with the page originally until I changed to prepared statements.

Comment: You should adapt your code to resemble the first example at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: @JuliePelletier it's indeed a duplicate, but *besides*, the OP have to make at least a single glance into PHP manual, in order to get an example for get_result() usage.